# I have to find out that the list contains at least 5 records or not

Tags: c#, linq, query-performance

```
int count1 = db.Salaries.Take(5).Count();
int count2 = db.Salaries.Count();
```

Question: I have to find out that the list contains at least 5 records or not. This list is having records of more than 5000.

From the above two count statements (`count1` and `count2`), which statement will give better performance? And what will be generated Sql query of the above two?

Comment: You should be able to find the generated query yourself. If you don't know how to do it now, that's the first thing to research. (It doesn't help that we don't know which LINQ technology you're using at the moment.)

Comment: (You almost certainly don't want those first two lines of code, by the way. Or if you *do* already need all the salaries in a list, then you don't need to go back to the database to see how many there are.)

Comment: Yes, Jon, please ignore above 2 lines. I want to know how Count() method behaves. Whether it traverses all the records to get the count. OR using Take(5) before Count() method will increases performance.

Comment: Rather than ask readers to ignore irrelevant parts of your question, please just avoid putting them in there in the first place from now on. And again, you should be able to determine the query that's issued yourself. You're in a much better position to do so than we are, given that we don't know whether you're using Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL or something else.

Comment: Your talking about micro-optimizations. If it's so important because you're developing a extremely time-critical application, you shouldn't use LINQ, or maybe even not C# in the first place. Else don't waste time on these micro-optimizations. Just program what your want to do. e.g. `if (foo.Count()>=5) [then]`.